# CFL bulb burnout damaging fitting?

Tags: cfl

I have two light fittings in my kitchen. Both have CFL bulbs which, as far as I can remember, were installed around the same time 10 years ago.

I was in the other room and heard this fizzling noise.  Went into the kitchen and saw that one of the bulbs had gone out.  Tried to put in a new bulb and it doesn't work.

I have read about how CFL bulbs act at the end of their life but can't find anything about them damaging light fittings.

Is this just a simple case of buying a new light fitting and swapping like for like or is this potentially something more serious that I need an electrician for?  (I would prefer to fix it myself as getting an electrician five days before Xmas is not going to be easy!)

Comment: You might revise to tell us something about the fixture. Replacing the fixture would likely solve the problem, but it's hard to say.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the fixture that failed and burned out the bulb on its way out? You should check the wiring from the panel to the light fixture to ensure that nothing happened to the wiring.

Answer (score 5):

Many times I have found the center conductor in the light socket has flattened out, lifting that tab away from the base with the power off will usually solve the problem. I have found some “electronic” lamps (not incandescent) do not have threads that are as long or a shoulder stops the lamp from being screwed in far enough. Lifting the tab will fix this also in many cases. Give lifting the tab a try.

Comment: Yes, the CFL/LED shoulder bottoming out and hitting the structure of the fixture is a common cause of poor socket contact.

Answer (score 1):

Had a chat with an electrician yesterday who said that when CFL bulbs reach the end of their life, sometimes there is a bit of burning that can damage the light fitting.  So I spent £2.95 and bought a new light fitting and wired it in and voila, I have light again.  Sometimes the simplest solution is the best...  :)